# Private Blogger API Calls without oauth2

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, blogger, google-oauth

I want to setup a private backup application that stores some web-application information (e.g. from Blogger.com) to my local storage using the Google Blogger API V3.0.

According to documentations I read, I always need OAuth2 (user interaction) to get my own private data like draft blog entries.

Now my question is, is it possible to implement the API calls without oauth2 to get my own private information? And if, how?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about that topic I maybe have a solution, but not sure if this is the best way ...
Implementing the backup rest service I created a form that takes over the Access Token request (manual interaction). The responded token with the refresh token gets stored in my backup-application.
So now, with each backup run, the service checks if a valid token is stored. If yes, the backup will be performed. If not, I get an email that prompts me to go to my application and request a new token with my request-form.

Overall this concept seems to work, but doesn't seems to be clean. Does anyone has a better concept?